# How to fix a fast, but broken internet connection?

Tags: internet

My Internet connection is fast enough, but it's very buggy.
for example, this is what you should see:

[image]

and this is what I see **most of the time**:

[image]

Each of my browsers (Chrome, IE, FF), breaks in a special way. one, loads halfway, another, once loads perfectly and once doesn't load at all and another loads badly in its own way and error model of each of them is not stable and differs.
problems of webpages and single pictures, differ from each other.
For example, sometimes, FF returns "Content encoding error" in loading webpages.

What I've done and I got nothing:

1- Restoring registry backups from fixes of my registry fix software.

2- Creating a fresh Admin user account and testing through it.

3- Testing with multiple browsers

4- Improving with CC, Perfect Disk, etc (other safe tools).

5- Changing IP and other needed items according to other stable connections of other PCs to test corrupted network settings.

6- closing firewall

7- Resetting IE settings

8- disabling/enabling wireless adapter

9- Applying Windows network diagnosis

10- Uninstalling/installing wireless adapter

11- Testing in "Safe mode with networking"

What I haven't done:

1- Full virus check (as I have always updated Avira and this is generally enough)

2- Reinstalling or repairing Windows (as It's time-consuming and due to other reasons)

Note:

1- Other computers that connect to the wireless that I connect to it too, have stable connection.

2- I don't know why, but my Avira can't be disabled.

I think this can be fixed easily, but I don't know how to do it.

---

New thoughts (after answering my own question):

It's strange! when Web Protection is enabled, no problem occurs for **HTTPS** sites.
It only has problem with HTTP sites. Also its problem is not always occurring and sometimes HTTP sites are correctly displayed.

Currently, after last update as in the past, Avira doesn't disable, but I managed to remove Web protection from uninstall page (modify feature) and now my internet is good, but still lose of Web protection and inability to disable Avira is annoying.

---

**Replies:**

1. Other computers that connect to the wireless that I connect to it too, have stable connection.
2. Most probably, but I want to choose reinstalling Windows as the last solution.
3. 2 GB and All of them have latest drivers.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is on your computer? Have you done a speedtest and contact your ISP's support? Its possible you have a failty connection that goes outside of your home. A mechanic can then fix the issue permanently.

Comment: 1 and 4 make me think the Windows install is broken now (if it wasn't before).

Comment: @AthomSfere - maybe or maybe not.   Mohsen: How much RAM does that computer contain? How about graphics hardware, RAM and drivers - up to date, old and limited? Add related info to your posting above!

Comment: If you try to do same thing with Linux and /or Mac OS X, this will make sure if the issue on Windows OS side or your ISP

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the image quality is a result of the JPEG not being done transfering/rendering properly. Anyone who's tried to surf the internet on a 33.6 modem in the 90's remembers this. So does those of us trying to view a hires (640x480!!!) on a 386 computer, because whatever algorithm is "sharpening" the image takes time to process.

What might be the cause of this can be several factors, but the most common one is a lot of packet loss. Here are some things to check out:

- Ensure you're not saturating your connections bandwidth by downloading something too fast at the same time.
- Ask your ISP about how your uplink signal is. If it's weak, that is the most likely cause.
- Test for packetloss. On windows, try `ping -t 8.8.8.8` and see if any packets are dropped.
- If the above doesn't look too bad, you need to gather some statistics: `pathping 8.8.8.8` (takes a while to run)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Avira Web Protection. When I disabled it, everything got correct. although it was after a full uninstall/install.

Comment: If this isn't the complete answer you are looking for, then you should add these details to the question and wait for an answer. Or post the answer to this question and ask another question, BUT don't ask another question in the answer.